# Why does cd ~k (& tab) expands to cd ~kernoops when I already have a folder named "~kernel-ppa" in pwd?

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a folder named `~kernel-ppa` inside `~/Downloads`.

```
aditya@aditya-desktop:~$ cd Downloads/
aditya@aditya-desktop:~/Downloads$ ls
~kernel-ppa
```

Now when I type `cd ~k` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> for automatic expansion, the shell expands it to `cd ~kernoops/` instead of `cd ~kernel-ppa/` although the folder with same starting characters is already present.

For automatic expansion to work, I need to escape it with `\`. Thus using `cd \~k` and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> correctly expands it to `cd \~kernel-ppa/`. Even using `cd \` and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> does the trick.

**Why is it so and why do I need to escape? Moreover, what am I escaping since even `~` is not required for automatic expansion?**

If I go with the flow and run `cd ~kernoops/` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the terminal status changes to `//`:

```
aditya@aditya-desktop:~/Downloads$ cd ~kernoops/
aditya@aditya-desktop://$ pwd
//
aditya@aditya-desktop://$ ls
bin   cdrom  etc   initrd.img  lost+found  mnt  proc  run   srv  tmp  var
boot  dev    home  lib         media       opt  root  sbin  sys  usr  vmlinuz
aditya@aditya-desktop://$
```

This looks like the `/` directory, but `pwd` says it is `//`. **What exactly is it?**

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Neither, it's "/home/aditya/Downloads/~kernel-ppa"

Comment: First, "cd ~kernoops/" is taking you to "cd /home/kernoops/" which doesn't exist. Instead, you get "cd //" which is another way of writing "cd /" - it's the root directory of the root filesystem, which does look odd.

Comment: As for why the single escape "\\" works, take a look at your folder with `tree` or with `ls` and you'll notice that happens to be the first sub-folder.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: I just noticed that since `~kernel-ppa` is the sole folder inside it; if I just run `cd ` and press tab, it expands to `cd \~kernel-ppa/`. I don't need to escape as well!

Comment: Yes. Also, if you keep pressing TAB you'll cycle through other available completions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you know, `~` expands to your home directory. But what you seem to have missed is that `~john` expands to the home directory of the user named "john".

Check your `/etc/passwd` file:

```
% grep ker /etc/passwd
kernoops:x:107:65534:Kernel Oops Tracking Daemon,,,:/:/bin/false
```

It has a "system user" named `kernoops` (for internal bug reporting reasons). So when you type `cd ~k`<kbd>Tab</kbd> the shell gives preference(1) to user name expansion before local directories expansion, and you have `cd ~kernoops`. Now  it results that user "kernoops" home dir is `/`, so it `cd`s to it.

In my shell, `zsh`, I have no double slash(2):

```
[:/] % cd ~kernoops/ 
[:/] % pwd
/
[:/] % cd //
[:/] % pwd
/
```

As an aside, this directory name is not well thought. It will need triple care in scripts and whatever. The only worst idea I can think is embedding a tab in it...

---

*Footnotes:*

(1) In `zsh`, even if I have a directory named `~xdir` and no user starting with `x`; doing `cd ~x`<kbd>Tab</kbd> does not expand and not quoting the `~` gives error:

```
[:~/tmp/x] %  mkdir \~xdir
[:~/tmp/x] % ls
~xdir
[:~/tmp/x] % cd ~xdir  
zsh: no such user or named directory: xdir
[:~/tmp/x] 1 %
```

(2) I seem to remember that posix made an exception for the initial `//` in a path --- it should be maintained because some old unix variant (I used the [apollos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Computer) with Domain/OS that had that) used `//machine-name/...` to seamless access other machines' filesystem in the local network (security was not invented yet). So probably bash is right here. If you do `cd ///` you will have the normal `/` in both shell, though.

Yes, [found on unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12283/unix-difference-between-path-starting-with-and)!

Comment: Another well-known legacy OS uses double-slash notation like that, but its slashes are typically written backwards and I'm not certain whether it accepts forward slashes for accessing network-remote filesystems like that. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

The tilde character (`~`) has a special meaning in the shell. When it is seen in any command, it is expanded to the name of your home directory.
Doing `cd ~` or `cd /home/aditya` is the same, it ends up in your home directory.

By putting a backslash character (`\`) in front of the tilde, you tell the shell to not do the expansion of the following special character (this is what is called shell escape).
By doing `cd \~` you ask the shell to move to a directory called `~` that would be located under the directory you are doing the command.
So doing `cd \~kernel-ppa` will change you to the directory called `~kernel-ppa`, which is the normal behaviour.

**EDITED: more on ~**

If you write a username of your system after the `~`, you are moved to the home directory of that user. Doing a <kbd>Tab</kbd> expansion after `cd ~` will expand to usernames existing on your system.
If do <kbd>Tab</kbd> completion after `cd ~k`, it expands to ~kernoops because there is user named *kernoops* in the system user, with a home directory of `/`.
As the expansion of `cd ~k` results into `cd ~kernoops/` with a trailing slash and the home directory beeing `/`, you are moved to `//`. 
But this is strictly the same as `/` as someothers already said earlier.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The combination of yours and @Rmano's answers clears the confusion completely :)